# xcode tvos app exiting issue when overriding menu button

Tags: xcode, menu, tvos

I am currently writing a tvOS app. I've been detecting and overriding the menu button with tapRecognizer to switch between storyboards and other functions. My issue is when I am on my home screen and press menu it does not exit the app. Instead it remembers the last function I used when overriding the menu button and performs that function. Any thoughts on how to clear the tapRecognizer? Or a function that will exit the app?

I'm overriding the menu button with

in Storyboard1

```
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(home)];
tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = @[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPressTypeMenu]];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

in my home subroutine I send the user back to my home page storyboard. But from then on the menu button will not exit the app but send me back to storyboard1.
thanks,
SW

Comment: This is my code and working fine for me, Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634638/how-to-handle-menu-button-action-in-tvos-remote/41426885#41426885

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using your own gesture recognizer, override pressesBegan:

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
  if(presses.first?.type == UIPressType.Menu) {
    // handle event
  } else {
    // perform default action (in your case, exit)
    super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this method. Were do I but this code? In the viewdidload?

Comment: That method should be added to your UIViewController

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean added it anywhere in my .m file or in the @implementation ViewController{   }?

Comment: You need something like this when changing scenes or when getting rid of gestures

Comment: I am working on Apple Tv application. This app is based on play video. My requirement is that when user pause the video and press the menu button, the video play continuous. I want on video pause state that the user press the menu button then the screen redirect to a previous screen without play video.

Answer (score 5):

You have to override 2 methods to prevent exiting app by pressing Menu button.

Here is ready-to-use template:

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        switch press.type {
        case .Menu:
            break
        default:
            super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}

override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        switch press.type {
        case .Menu:
            //Do some staff there!
            self.menuButtonPressed()
        default:
            super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of responding to presses, all you need to do is to disable the recognizer:

```
tapRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

So if no recognizer with `UIPressTypeMenu` is listening, tvOS suspends the app and displays the home screen. (I've tested this)

Answer (score 2):

If you overwrite the menu button, the app won't be accepted:

EDIT: You can overwrite, but the menu button has to work as a back button to homescreen from the entry point of the app.

> #### 10.1 Details
>
> The Menu button on the Siri Remote does not behave as expected in your
>   app.
>
> Specifically, when the user launches the app and taps the Menu button
>   on the Siri remote, the app does not exit to the Apple TV Home screen.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to ensure that the Siri remote buttons behave
>   as expected and comply with the Apple TV Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Is this true? I know of a few apps that don't exit when you press the Menu button. I think it makes sense for it to exit to the home screen IF it's at the entry point of the application, ie it's own home screen. But I have seen apps like Hungry Shark Evolution which don't exit when pressing menu button.  It's used more as a BACK button in that game. But even on main menu it won't exit back to the Apple TV home screen

Comment: Yes, you are right.  But on the entry-ViewController it has to lead back to the home screen, so overwrite it only if neccessary.

Comment: I need to know how to conditionally handle the button press. In other words, how do I exit to the home screen programmatically (ideally without killing the app)?

Answer (score 0):

It may be help you...
it is swift code.

```
let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.menuButtonAction(_:)))
menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.hashValue)]
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's documentation, for custom press handling, we should override all four of these methods-

```
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesChanged:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesCancelled:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

This is the official documentation from XCode:

> Generally, all responders which do custom press handling should
>   override all four of these methods.
>
> Your responder will receive either pressesEnded:withEvent or pressesCancelled:withEvent: for each
>
> press it is handling (those presses it received in pressesBegan:withEvent:).
>
> pressesChanged:withEvent: will be invoked for presses that provide
>   an analog value
>   (like thumbsticks or analog push buttons)
>
> *** You must handle cancelled presses to ensure correct behavior in
>   your application.  Failure to
>   do so is very likely to lead to incorrect behavior or crashes.

Answer (score 0):

### SwiftUI Seekers:

I don't know how much this answer helps, but just adding available actions in SwiftUI.

```
YourAnyView
  .onExitCommand(perform: {
      print("onExitCommand")
  })
  .onMoveCommand { direction in
      print("onMoveCommand", direction)
  }
```

#### REF:

[onmovecommand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/onmovecommand(perform:))

[onexitcommand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/onexitcommand(perform:))