# How to handle Menu Button action in tvOS remote

Tags: swift, focus, tvos, presentviewcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

I am facing the strange problem with my application. Actually when i am presenting a view controller for play the video. At the video load time user press the menu button the application goes to background. While i have overwrite the Menu Button Action.

This is my code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(VideoPlayerViewController.menuButtonAction(_:)))
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.hashValue)]
    self.playerController.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}

func menuButtonAction(ges:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismissView()
 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is my code and working for me.

**Swift 3**

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.menuButtonAction(recognizer:)))
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}

func menuButtonAction(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 4**

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.menuButtonAction(recognizer:)))
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}

@objc func menuButtonAction(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Swift 4.2 & 5**

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let menuPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    menuPressRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.menuButtonAction(recognizer:)))
    menuPressRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(menuPressRecognizer)
}

@objc func menuButtonAction(recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the UITapGestureRecognizer solution is more ideal than overriding the presses withEvent methods if you're also overriding shouldUpdateFocus and preferredFocusEnvironments. Because UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't cancel the other focus events, where as the presses overrides do.

Answer (score 5):

You should use enum's `rawValue` instead of `hash` when you specify `allowedPressTypes`:

`menuPressRecognizer = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.menu.rawValue)]`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to multiple add multiple values you can do simple:

```
let pressTypes: [NSNumber] = [UIPressType.select, UIPressType.playPause, UIPressType.rightArrow].map{ NSNumber(value: $0.rawValue)}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in IB. There's an option on TapGestureRecognizer for buttons which includes the menu button.

Answer (score 0):

For more granularity, you can also make use of the following methods:

```
- (void)pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesChanged:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesEnded:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)pressesCancelled:(NSSet<UIPress *> *)presses withEvent:(nullable UIPressesEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

Please make sure to override all of these methods if you choose to use any of them as per Apple's suggestions given below:

> Generally, all responders which do custom press handling should
>   override all four of these methods.
>
> Your responder will receive either pressesEnded:withEvent or
>   pressesCancelled:withEvent: for each
>
> press it is handling (those presses it received in
>   pressesBegan:withEvent:).
>
> pressesChanged:withEvent: will be invoked for presses that provide an
>   analog value (like thumbsticks or analog push buttons)
>
> *** You must handle cancelled presses to ensure correct behavior in your application. Failure to do so is very likely to lead to incorrect
>   behavior or crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
private func setupRemoteGesture() {
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleMenuPress))
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.menu.rawValue)]
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc private func handleMenuPress() {
    // Menu button pressed
}
```